# XSLT Moving an Element to an other Node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having the following problem.

I have this XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <first>a</first>
    <third>
        <goal>b</goal>
    </third>
</root>
```

And I need it in this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <first>a</first>
    <second>
        <goal>b</goal>
    </second>
</root>
```

So I thought XSLT would be the right tool for me but I don't get it working.

Thats my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="/root/third/goal">
                   <goal><xsl:value-of select="."/></goal>
        </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help will be welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the `third` element then you need to write a template doing that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="root/third[goal]">
        <second>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </second>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I posted a complete stylesheet that implements the transformation you asked for in your question. If you have a different input you need to edit your question or ask a new one, providing the necessary details, like the XSLT you have, the input you have, the output you want and the one you get.